# PowerShell complaining about path, But path is valid

Tags: powershell, rename-item-cmdlet

In the following code, when $client = XRS1

```
if (Test-Path C:\dbbackups\cm_$client-*.full.bak){
Rename-Item -path C:\dbbackups\cm_$client-*.bak -newname cm_$client.bak
Write-Host "New file found, renamed to: cm_$client.bak"
```

The Test-Path statement can find C:\dbbackups\cm_xrs1-2013414.full.full.bak but -path in the Rename-Item can't.

The error I get is

```
Rename-Item : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "path" is not valid. Change the value of the "path" argument and run the operation again.
At C:\Users\Aaron\Documents\0000 - PowerShell DB Update Utility\UpdateCMDatabases.ps1:167 char:1
+ Rename-Item -path C:\dbbackups\cm_$client-*.bak -newname cm_$client.bak
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Rename-Item], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Rename-Item does not like a wildcard, then do not give it one

```sh
Convert-Path C:\dbbackups\cm_$client-*.full.bak | % {
  if (Test-Path $_) {
    Rename-Item $_ cm_$client.bak
  }
}
```

Comment: won't this lose files, since you're renaming all the items that match the wildcard to the same name?

Comment: @Eris that issue appears to be in the original question as well. So Steven is preserving the bug.

Comment: @Eris a pipe to `select -f 1` can fix it

Comment: Thanks for the Answer Steven, it worked perfectly! The renaming files to same name was intended. Although the intent is to get the newest one and delete the rest, so I may have to go in an explicitly code for that.

Answer (score 15):

For those who need only a one line command, please note that this is a powershell only error and that this command works just fine in the good old command prompt.

The full form of the powershell command is

```
ren -Path [something with a wildcard] -NewName [something else]
```

The error relates to the value of the Path parameter. It accepts wildcards in the path but it must resolve to a single file [[1]](https://andrwwatt.wordpress.com/2006/05/13/limitations-of-the-rename-item-cmdlet/). To use wildcards with powershell, you'll need to pipe them one by one to the rename item command. Here is an example to rename txt files to log [[2]](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849763.aspx):

```
get-childItem *.txt | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace '\.txt','.log' }
```